Polynomial and rational representations of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$
Let $G = GL_n(\mathbb{C})$.
A rational representation of $G$ is a group homomorphism $\varphi: G \to GL(V)$, where $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, and $\varphi$ is given by rational functions. In other words, the matrix entries of $\varphi(A)$ are rational functions in the entries of $A \in G$.
A polynomial representation of $G$ is a group homomorphism $\varphi_0: G \to GL(V)$ where the matrix entries of $\varphi_0(A)$ are polynomial functions in the entries of $A \in G$.
The book that I am reading states the following result, which explains why we can restrict ourselves to polynomial representations. However, it does not provide a proof or a reference for the proof.

For any rational representation $\varphi: G \to GL(V)$, there exists a polynomial representation $\varphi_0: G \to GL(V)$ and an integer $k$ such that:
$$
\varphi = \varphi_0 \circ \mathrm{det}^k.
$$

I have looked through Fulton and Harris but could not find this proposition or its proof, and I am wondering if I might have missed it. Could you kindly point me to a reference of a proof of this result?

Forget about representations, this is just a fact about rational functions.  Every rational function from $GL_n$ to $\mathbb{A}^k$ can be made polynomial by multiplying by a power of the determinant.

The problem is not to do with representations or algebraic groups.
Given a (single) polynomial $f$ in $n$ variables its zero locus defines an affine algebraic variety. Actually its non-zero locus, that is the set of points in ${\mathbf k}^n$ where $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\ne0$ is also an affine algebraic variety with co-ordinate ring isomorphic to the quotient ring of $n+1$ varibale polynomial ring: ${\mathbf k}[x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n, x_{n+1}]/I$ with $I$ being the principal ideal generated by $x_{n+1}f(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)-1$. In this quotient ring the coset of $x_{n+1}$ is the reciprocal of  $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. (on the set where $f$ is nonzero, the affine variety we are focussed on.)  And hence a polynomial function  of $n+1$ variables can be represented on this variety by a rational function of first $n$ variables  replacing $x_{n+1}^m$ by $f^{-m}$.
Now $GL_n$ is the special  case where $f$ is the determinant polynomial in $n^2$ variables.
